# "Reading up" law?

Tags: international, academia

I am currently taking an undergraduate Introduction to International Law course. In an email to the students regarding an upcoming case brief, my professor clarified that one part of the rationale section should include

> what does the Court say about the law, what does it do with the law
>   (read it up, read it down, etc.)?

I have searched the internet while it is common knowledge what "reading down" means, I could not find any reference to "reading up."

Was this an error by my professor where he really meant "reading in" or is there really a concept of reading up in international law?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://english.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This is an English language and colloquial usage question, not a question about the law.

Comment: Yes it is an English language term, but the OP may not know that it is not a legal term unless answered (e.g. reading the law - becoming a lawyer without going to law school)

Comment: I’ve never heard this term either but I assume it simply refers to the opposite of ‘reading down,’ that is, adopting a broad interpretation rather than a narrow one.

Comment: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/read-up-on-about-sth

Comment: I think that this is on topic since it is terminology being used in relation to legal matters, but I've never seen that usage myself. It could refer to narrowing or broadening the effort of the plain terms of the legal instrument related to whether treaties are or are not self-executing, but it is hard to tell.

Comment: @scaaahu I don't think that the sense of the phrase found in that dictionary is what is intended in the context in which the words are being used here.

Comment: @scaaahu, I found that before posting, and my English is not bad. I was asking if it had a legitimate use in the legal context my professor - who has a Masters in Law from Yale - used it in.

Comment: @ohwilleke is correct on both accounts.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch, my question is not if it is an English phrase, it is a question in terms of the principles of legal interpretation. I was wondering if it was possible that, in International Law, since there is no stare decisis, reading up occurs as opposed to reading in.